# No eth0 device on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, ethernet

**EDIT: 2020-02-17 I bought a ethernet network card in the end.**

without knowing what has changed on my Ubuntu 18.04, no wired ethernet device is found anymore. Could you help me get my wired ehternet back?

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1480
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1481
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1483
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1483
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1484
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1482
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1484
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1484
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1484
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1440
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1441
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1442
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1443
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1444
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1445
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1446
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1447
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57ad
02:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57a3
02:03.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57a3
02:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57a4
02:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57a4
02:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 57a4
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a824
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1485
05:00.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 149c
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 149c
06:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
07:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 148a
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1485
0a:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1486
0a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 149c
0a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1487
0b:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
0c:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
    docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
    ether 02:42:38:4e:4f:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 3218  bytes 312722 (312.7 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3218  bytes 312722 (312.7 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 2a02:8070:7ae:2a00:cace:4483:6c6b:a4e4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::92b2:9393:9296:2687  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2a02:8070:7ae:2a00:a5c7:5318:862f:3ee1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether d4:5d:64:95:fe:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 64655  bytes 44361545 (44.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 52497  bytes 11641540 (11.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**lshw -C network**

```
-network                 
           description: Wireless interface
           product: RTL8192CE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           logical name: wlp4s0
           version: 01
           serial: d4:5d:64:95:fe:93
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=5.4.0-65-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.115 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:101 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:e0300000-e0303fff
```

**journalctl -b | grep network**

```
 kernel: drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
 systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...
 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
 systemd[1]: Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
 NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1612964125.8635] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
 NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1612964125.8975]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
 NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1612964125.8975]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
 networkd-dispatcher[1031]: WARNING: systemd-networkd is not running, output will be incomplete.
 systemd[1]: Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
 systemd[1266]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
 systemd[1266]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
 NetworkManager[1024]: <info>  [1612964128.1595] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.
 systemd[1796]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
 systemd[2103]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
```

**I also checked for kernel driver errors via dmesg | grep -i eth**

```
but grep did not find anything
```

I can confirm thet the ethernet Realtek Lan controller is enabled in the BIOS. I also booted from Ubuntu Live USB with equal results as

Comment: Please add output of `lspci`.

Comment: added lspci to the question

Comment: Confirm that the ethernet card is enabled in your BIOS. Also, try and boot to a Ubuntu Live USB/DVD and see if the ethernet works then. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I can confirm thet the ethernet Realtek Lan controller is enabled in the BIOS. I also booted from Ubuntu Live USB with equal results. No eth device is poping up, only the wirles card. Any suggestions, mainboard broken?

Comment: Go back to the BIOS, note any special settings that you've made, and then choose RESET TO FACTORY DEFAULTS, then reboot, and recheck ethernet. Report back.

Comment: I ended up buying a new card for 10 EUR.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have lost HW Eth.
According to `lshw` there is only Wireless adapter and so `wlp4s0`.
Anything in `dmesg` during boot showing any issue with detection of HW eth port ?
If not onboard eth, then were there any recent changes to physical box .. might be just loose card in slot.

Comment: Hey, it is an onboard eth. I did include the dmesg from boot time, nothing unordinary reporting there. This is really strange, seems to be a problem with mainboard... . The desktop is not touched. It may be a little bit cold around the desktops location but nothing else. Do you have any experience with onboard eth loose?